# Show an overlapping object in three.js when using an alpha map

Tags: three.js

In my three.js project I have two objects. One is a golden ring and the other one is a diamond. Now I would like to "cut out" a piece of the ring and place a frame for the diamond in the hole.

I created an alpha map for testing and applied it to the ring material. I also positioned the diamond to be above the point where the ring is now transparent.

[image: ring and diamond]

Everything seems to work fine, except that I still can't see the diamond "inside" the ring. After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648067/three-js-drawing-two-overlapping-transparent-spheres-and-hiding-intersection) I have set `renderOrder` to 1 on the diamond but this does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the end it turned out to be a very stupid mistake. I forgot to set `transparent: true` on the material.